# SSSD integration with Ldap Error 'Could not start TLS encryption. TLS: hostname does not match CN in peer certificate'

Tags: ssl, ldap, openldap, sssd

We are currently using Wildcard certificate with SAN. I can successfully run ldapsearch from my client machine when I added ***TLS_REQSAN allow*** in openldap configuration.

Now i'm trying to integrate SSSD with secure LDAP but getting the below error

'***Could not start TLS encryption. TLS: hostname does not match CN in peer certificate***'

How can I force SSSD to check for Subject Alternate Name(SAN) instead of CN.

Is there a property I could set in SSSD configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this error by adding the below property in sssd.conf under domain

```
krb5_use_enterprise_principal = True
```